# how to get a redis-queue job from a job id

Tags: python, redis, celery, message-queue

I want to switch a python web application from using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) to [Redis-Queue (rq)](http://python-rq.org).

In Celery, to get the task with a given `task_id`, I use:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id)  # celery
```

In redis-queue, I can see two possible ways to do it:

```
job = Job(job_id, connection=connection)        # first way
job = Job.fetch(job_id, connection=connection)  # second way
```

They both seem to work.  Is one preferred over the other?  Or is there another way?

thanks

Comment: I have the same question, but find the docs on RQ site very limited.